# Why is my array throwing Out of Range Exception Error?

Tags: c#, arrays

Why does the following code throw an exception?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Items.Length-1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Items[i,1]);
}
```

Exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message="Index was outside the bounds of the array."
  Source="Es"
  StackTrace:
       at Es.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Fero\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\Es\Es\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Declaration of Items:

Function which gets the array of strings:

```
static string[,] ReadFromFile(string filename, int rowsF)
{
    StreamReader SR;
    string S;
    string[] S_split;

    SR = File.OpenText(filename);
    S = SR.ReadLine();

    string[,] myItems = new String[rowsF, 2];
    int row_number = 0;
    while (S != null)
    {
        S_split = S.Split('"');
        //temp_items[row_number,0] = 
        myItems[row_number,0] = S_split[1];
        myItems[row_number,1] = S_split[2];

        row_number++;
        S = SR.ReadLine();
    }
    SR.Close();
    return myItems;
}

string[,] Items = ReadFromFile(myFile, rowsF);
```

Comment: What does the array declaration look like?

Comment: Can you include the declaration of Items?

Comment: I've added some stuff to post

Comment: line 119 is (Console.WriteLine) ?

Comment: If it's short enough, can we see the input file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a straight two-dimensional array. Length gives you the [total number of elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) in the array, but you're using it to calculate the index for a single dimension. What you want is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Items.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Items[i,1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the length of Items[i]. It appears to be a 2D array, and it's apparently not null, because you'd get a different exception for that, so it probably is just an empty array at Items[i], or only contains one item.

Check for:

```
Items[i] == null
Items[i].Length > 0
```

**EDIT**: Your additional code helped. When you split the string to initialize Items, for the item that's giving you trouble, check what you're storing at index 1. Other than that, I can't see a problem with it.

Comment: There are two columns in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an exception because `Items[i].Length` is < 2

you need to check that `(Items[i].Length >= 2)` before trying to access `Items[i,1]`

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean in here.. What "Item" ??

Comment: sorry, it's Items (the 2d array you have)

Comment: The second dimension is large enough, it's the first dimension index that gives the exception. Items.GetLength(0) < Items.Length.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there's a small chance one of the lines doesn't follow the format you require.  It looks like you're retrieving text based on Quote (") delimitation, and  S_split[] might not always have those number of fields.

A blank line at the end of the file, for example, will trigger the exception.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     S_split = S.Split('"');
>     //temp_items[row_number,0] = 
>     myItems[row_number,0] = S_split[1];
>     myItems[row_number,1] = S_split[2];
> ```

Are you sure you don't want S_Split[0] & S_Split[1]?

Should see the input file.

Comment: no, I checked the values .. my .dat file contains "something" xxxxxx and I need to get something and xxxxx